# Where to find mono-service2 after mono installed?

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I have installed mono on ubuntu 16.04 as the doc:

http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-ubuntu

but I can't run mono-service2

the system told me it can't been find

I run

find / -name mono-service2

got error:find: ./run/user/1000/gvfs:not have permission

so how can I use mono-service2

Comment: You should use `mono-service` I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get this error because you did not run find command with sudo attributes

try like this to search only executables

```
sudo find / -executable -name mono-service2
```

otherwise, you can try also with

```
whereis mono-service2
```

or

```
which mono-service2
```